# What is the best non-SAS IDE for the SAS Language?

Tags: ide, sas

I am working on SAS code that will run under UNIX.  Ideally the IDE will have:

- intelligent code formatting (autocomplete is not necessary).
- ability to transfer code to server via SFTP/SSH/SCP.
- Ability to execute code on the server via ssh and -e
- Ability to pull the logs back down and have those formatted as well.

Thoughts?

I'm looking at MultiEdit Lite for SAS (it seems to have the functionality but actually LOOKS horrible.. so bad its distracting).  Any others?  Can Eclipse act as a SAS IDE?

Comment: To arbitrarily close this question suddenly after it having stood as a valid and useful (top tier of score for the tag before it started getting downvoted AFTER you closed it, top 30 favorited questions for the tag, etc.) question for users of the site for over 4 years.  At the very least, consider moving it to PROGRAMMER (which didn't even exist at the time).  I know its fashionable to close questions to "clean up the site" but consider that this question was voted up many times as useful (before the closing moderators ever even JOINED Stack Overflow) in a VERY niche tag to begin.

Comment: Also, ironically, I earned the "notable question badge" for this question; which should be a context clue that this isn't categorically off-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't tried it yet, but it looks like using myEclipse along with the **[plugin SLink](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=254574&package_id=312831)** from anixma, will provide support for everything listed, including SSH execution of code on remote UNIX servers as well as local execution if you've got sas.exe already installed.

Answer (score 1):

VSick from SlickEdit inc can do this - and more.

It is not free, but it is powerful.

Answer (score 0):

If you use emacs (or XEmacs) then you could look at [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/).  I haven't tested it much, but it might do what you need.  See in particular [here](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#ESS-for-SAS).

Answer (score 0):

Ultraedit or EditPlus.  Both have excellent FTP, project management and ties ins to version COntrol.  Syntax highlighting and tool creation are also in there, plus excellent serah/rep[lace functions.

Comment: Is this even relevant to the SAS IDE discussion?